# Cloud functions error: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Trying to use the admin SDK from Firebase to set custom claims within Firebase Cloud Functions. The issue seems to be the claims object I pass into the function. I understand what a circular object structure is, but I'm not sure why it is happening here.

**The Error:**

[image: Firebase Error report]

Here is the cloud function code

```
exports.setCustomClaims2 = functions.https.onCall((uid, claims) => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,claims).then(() => {
            return {
                message: `Success! User updated with claims`
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        })
});
```

And here is the front end code to call it:

```
let uid = "iNj5qkasMdYt43d1pnoEAIewWWC3";
let claims = {admin: true};

const setCustomClaims = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('setCustomClaims2');
setCustomClaims(uid,claims)
```

---

What is interesting is that when I replace the claims parameter directly in the cloud function call like so

`admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{admin: true})`

This seems to work just fine.

Is there a difference in how the object gets received as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the callable type function correctly.  As you can see from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), the function you pass to the SDK always receives two arguments, `data` and `context`, no matter what you pass from the app.  A **single** object you pass from the app becomes the **single** `data` parameter.  You can't pass multiple parameters, and that parameter doesn't get broken up into multiple parameters.

What you should do instead is combine uid and claims into a single object, and pass it:

```
setCustomClaims({ uid, claims })
```

Then receive it as a single parameter in the function:

```
exports.setCustomClaims2 = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // data here is the single object you passed from the client
    const { uid, claims } = data;
})
```

I'll note that using console.log in the function will help you debug what your function is doing.  If you logged the values of `uid` and `claims`, this probably would have been easier to figure out.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes so much sense now :)